# Method ran when user press Back key on Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm developing an Android 2.2 application.

I want to know which activity method is ran when user press back key.

I have found this: 
*"When the user presses the BACK key, the current activity is popped from the stack, and the previous one resumes as the running activity. "*

But it doesn't tell what method is ran.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android 2.2, pressing the BACK button triggers `onBackPressed()` in your activity. The default implementation of `onBackPressed()` calls `finish()`.

Comment: And, I'm suppose, this activity will be destroyed, isn't it?

Comment: @VansFannel: That's what `finish()` does, basically the passage you have quoted in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`onKeyDown` and `onBackPressed`